# Load JSON file in current distribution of a python package using pkg_resources

Tags: python, json, package

I am building a package that has the following directory structure -

```
terraai_preprocessing
|setup.py
||MANIFEST.in
|terraai_preprocessing
  |__init__.py
  |combinatorics
  |preprocessing
    |__init__.py
    |config.json
    |pp_main.py
    |pp_helpers.py
```

I am trying to load config.json into pp_helpers.py using pkg_resources, as mentioned on other similar questions. I am sure the file exists because -

```
>>print resource_exists('terraai_preprocessing.preprocessing', 'config.json')
>>True
```

I have tried using the following but ended up with errors, -

```
>>with open(resource_filename('terraai_preprocessing.preprocessing', 'config.json'),'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

 >>config = json.loads(resource_filename('terraai_preprocessing.preprocessing', 'config.json'))
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

 >>config = json.loads(resource_stream('terraai_preprocessing.preprocessing', 'config.json'))
enter code here

 >>config = json.loads(resource_string('terraai_preprocessing.preprocessing', 'config.json'))
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python could not find the file as the function `resource_filename()` returns the address with `\\` as separators. By replacing `\\` with `/` it was able to locate the file.

So I used the following code -

```
>> file_location = resource_filename('terraai_preprocessing.preprocessing','config.json').replace('\\',"/")

>> with open(file_location,'r') as f:
      config = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to be like:

```
with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
```

so in your case

```
 config = json.loads(f.read())
```

Comment: No this doesn't work, I get a no such file or directory error. Since config.json is a package resource, I dont think I can directly access it like that.

Comment: replace data.json with config.json and if your file is in the same directory provide path ./config.json or absolute path from the directory root

Comment: Yes, I did replace the file name correctly, and provided the correct path. Have tried with the absolute path as well using - `resource_filename('terraai_preprocessing.preprocessing', 'config.json')`
But it still throws `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './config.json' `

Comment: run pwd and verify where you are, than prep-end the output of pwd to '/config.json' - /your found path/config.json

Comment: The pwd came out to `C:\Windows\system32` so that's not where the file is. I tried getting the full path with `resource_filename('terraai_preprocessing.preprocessing', 'config.json')`
the path is correct but `config = json.load(f)` results in `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: Then your file does not contain a valid json - edit it to verify the JSON format is valid.

Comment: Yes I found an error in my JSON, but the intial problem was not due to that, I found out the right way to go about it. Please see my answer below.